# Entity Framework, table with 2 foreign keys to 2 different tables

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

I have 3 models with fields in it like the following:

```
public class RootObject
{
    [Key]
    public int RootObjectId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("RootObjectId")]
    public virtual AObject AObject { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("RootObjectId")]
    public virtual BObject BObject { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class AObject
{
    [Key]
    public int AObjectId { get; set; }

    //Other fields
}

public class BObject
{
    [Key]
    public int BObjectId { get; set; }

    //Other fields
}
```

I want it so that if I were to visually inspect the `RootObject` table I would see see a list of `RootObjectId`'s and `Name`'s.  For ease, lets assume even numbered `RootObjectId`'s are mapped to `AObjectId`'s and odds are mapped to `BObjectId`'s.  If I were to visually inspect `AObject`, I would expect to see the ID's 2, 4, 6, ... that are FK's for `RootObject`.  If were to visually inspect `BObject`, I would expect to see the ID's 1, 3, 5, ... that are FK's for `RootObject`.

Currently, when I try this approach I get the following error:

"An error occurred while updating the entries...Referential integrity constraint violations. A Dependent Role has multiple principals with different values."

I tried to remove the FK attributes in `RootObject` but that created 2 additional columns in `RootObject` that were populated with ID numbers.  I don't want this since every `RootObject` has either one `AObject` or one `BObject`.  It can't have both.

Comment: It can't even be done in SQL, let alone EF.

Answer (score 1):

To me, you are looking for something for which the TPT (Table per Type) approach in Entity Framework could be a solution. Applied to your case (there are many approaches, but this I tested and it works):

```
public class RootObject
{
    [Key]
    public int RootObjectId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[Table("AObjects")]
public class AObject : RootObject
{
    //Other fields
    public string AField { get; set; }
}

[Table("BObjects")]
public class BObject : RootObject
{
    //Other fields
    public string BField { get; set; }
}
```

For the DbContext class:

```
public DbSet<RootObject> RootObjects { get; set; }
public DbSet<AObject> AObjects { get; set; }
public DbSet<BObject> BObjects { get; set; }
```

Seed example:

```
AObject a1 = new AObject() { Name = "ImA", AField = "adata" };
BObject b1 = new BObject() { Name = "ImB", BField = "bdata" };
context.AObjects.Add(a1);
context.BObjects.Add(b1);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to use ONE column to be a foreign key to two different tables. You should rather think of two (optional) FK like:

```
public class RootObject
{
    [Key]
    public int RootObjectId { get; set; }

    public int? EvensAObjectId { get; set; }
    public int? OddsBObjectId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("EvensAObjectId")]
    public virtual AObject AObject { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("OddsBObjectId")]
    public virtual BObject BObject { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To set up 1-0..1 relationships you need to define the relationships explicitly during model configuration.

```
public class Model1 : DbContext
{
    public Model1()
        : base("name=Model1")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<AObject>()
            .HasRequired(e => e.RootObject).WithOptional(r => r.AObject);

        modelBuilder.Entity<BObject>()
            .HasRequired(e => e.RootObject).WithOptional(r => r.BObject);

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    public virtual DbSet<RootObject> RootObjects { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AObject> AObjects { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<BObject> BObjects { get; set; }
}


public class RootObject
{
    [Key]
    public int RootObjectId { get; set; }
    public virtual AObject AObject { get; set; }
    public virtual BObject BObject { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class AObject
{
    [Key]
    public int AObjectId { get; set; }

    public virtual RootObject RootObject { get; set; }
}

public class BObject
{
    [Key]
    public int BObjectId { get; set; }

    public virtual RootObject RootObject { get; set; }
}
```

You'll want to be really careful when setting `RootObject.AObject` and `RootObject.BObject`, as if there is already a related row you will get an error when you save. Also, I don't think there's any way to get EF enforce the constraint that each RootObject must have either an AObject or a BObject, but not both - you'd need to enforce that in your code.